# I can't send a post request to test my login functionality in postman

Tags: node.js, post, postman

Today I've started to develop my first web application. I decided to use Node JS and MySQL ( and also Vue JS ). I am trying to create a script for login / register. The register works good. I tested the request in Postman and all looks ok. The problem comes on login. The request I send with Postman takes too long, and I don't know why.

That's my server.js file:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
)

var Users = require('./routes/Users')

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port)
})
```

And the login route:

```js
users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          })
          res.send(token)
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    })
})
```

I want the request to send the correct response.
The executed mysql seems ok:

```sql
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `created` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`email` = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1;
```

But I don't know why takes so long. And also after 1-2 minutes I receive this:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/users/login.
```

Comment: Put console log in your code and check which line of code is braking

Comment: Check the dev tools console and make sure you're not getting any CORS errors first.

Comment: I think the problem is on this line, on route: if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {